# displaying bean class items on view - beginner

Tags: grails

The bean class looks like this:

String houseNo
String address
Person person

The view looks like this

```
<g:form action="save">
    <fieldset class="form">
        <g:render template="form" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <g:submitButton name="create" class="save"
            value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

According to my knowledge in Grails, i think is `<g:render template="form" />` will pull all form attributes and display it.

But what i want to do is Instead of displaying a drop-down for `Person`, i want to display all `Person` related fields like `personName`, `personAge`. How can i display these fields in a label underneath ?

Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct about the way g:render works, the template part refers to a GSP which will look through the bean values and print them according to the html + groovy markup in "_form.gsp" (located in your views folder under the controller name).

To change the way the Person domain object is displayed, simply edit this "_form.gsp" and take out the 'select' html code - replacing it with groovy markup using the property values of the bean, eg.

```
${beanName.person.personName} //(use the existing code to help workout the bean name etc)
```

Hopefully that helps you on your way.